# returning a filtered list from DB by a list of ids contained in another query with SQLAlchemy Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write an SQLAlchemy DB query that returns a list of `provider_service_files` that have **NOT** been assigned to a client:

**My first query gets all the service files that have been assigned to a user:**

```
client_resource_guide_urls = db_session.query(ClientResourceGuideUrl).filter(\
        ClientResourceGuideUrl.client_id == client_id).all()
```

returns a list with this output:

```
[
    {
        "client_id": 20,
        "id": 9,
        "service_file_url_id": 3
    },
    {
        "client_id": 20,
        "id": 10,
        "service_file_url_id": 2
    }
]
```

Using the `service_file_url_id` in that list, I query for `ServiceFileUrl` and if an entry contains an ID that is equal to any `service_file_url_id` I want that entry filtered out of the list.

```
   for client_resource_guide_url in client_resource_guide_urls:
        print(client_resource_guide_url) # only shows first entry
        service_files = db_session.query(ServiceFileUrl.id, ServiceFileUrl.service_id, \
            ServiceFileUrl.file_label, ServiceFileUrl.file_url, \
                ProviderService.name, ServiceFileUrl.provider_id,\
                    ServiceFileUrl.created_at)\
                        .select_from(ServiceFileUrl, ProviderService)\
                            .join(ProviderService).filter(\
                                ServiceFileUrl.provider_id == provider_id, \
                                    ServiceFileUrl.id != client_resource_guide_url.service_file_url_id).all()
```

This query is only filtering out the FIRST entry and not the second. A print of `client_resource_guide_url` only shows the first entry is being looped through. My approach is cleary not ideal here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leverage the power of SQL, rather than a Python loop, pass a list of values to the `Column.not_in()` function [ref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/operators.html#not-in).

```
ids_to_filter = [i['service_file_url_id'] for i in client_resource_guide_urls]
    
service_files = db_session.query(
    ServiceFileUrl.id,
    ServiceFileUrl.service_id,
    ServiceFileUrl.file_label,
    ServiceFileUrl.file_url,
    ProviderService.name,
    ServiceFileUrl.provider_id,
    ServiceFileUrl.created_at)\
    .select_from(
        ServiceFileUrl,
        ProviderService)\
    .join(ProviderService)\
    .filter(
        (ServiceFileUrl.provider_id == provider_id), \
        (ServiceFileUrl.id.not_in(ids_to_filter)))\
    .all()
```